# if parent has class doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

I don't understand something that doesn't work in my jQuery code. The HTML code is PHP generated so I need to edit it with jQuery. Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a>Biologie</a></li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a>Chimie</a></li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a>Non classé</a></li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a>Physique</a>
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a>Physique quantique</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

What I want is to add a specific css class to elements that have the "cat-item" css class but whose parents don't have the "children" css class. Here's my jQuery code:

```
    if( $(".cat-item").parent().hasClass("children") == false) {
      $(this).addClass( "list-group" );
    }
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. The code

```
$(".cat-item").addClass( "list-group" );
```

works so I'm sure (or quite sure) that it is a problem with the parent() or hasClass() functions.

Comment: because `this` is not the li

Comment: Why are the lis not in a ul?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the supplied HTML is invalid.

Comment: Invalid HTML, and not understanding how `this` works, seems to be the problem?

Comment: Hi, the HTML in the div container is generated with a wordpress function wp_list_categories()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says if the first parent of the .cat-item does not have a class, than add a class to something (what every the scope of this is).

If you want to add classes to the lis that are not in the ul with the class, than select those.

```js
$(".container ul")  //select the uls
  .not("ul.children")  //filter out the ones with the class
    .find("> .cat-item")  //select the direct descendants
      .addClass( "list-group" );  //add the class
```

```css
li {
   background-color: lime;
}

.list-group {
    background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a>Biologie</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a>Chimie</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a>Non classé</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a>Physique</a>
      <ul class='children'>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a>Physique quantique</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer too ! It helped me a lot. Have a good day !

Comment: And this way is better than the looping solution in my opinion which you selected.

Answer (score 2):

in what function do you put that `if` conditional ? if you put it inside `$(document).ready()` , `$(this)` would be `$(document)`

with that logic, you should use that `if` inside a function that is attached to `li`

i made a solution below using variables so it's easier to understand for you which is what :)

also added `ul` in your `html` structure which was missing ( careful about that )

see snippet below

```js
var cat = $("ul li.cat-item") // getting the li with class .cat-item
 $(cat).each(function() { // looping through all .cat-item elements
   var parentUL = $(this).parent("ul") // getting the parent of each li.cat-item 

   if (!$(parentUL).hasClass("children")) { //check if the parent doesn't have class children
     $(this).addClass("list-group"); //if YES > addClass to that li whose parent doesn't have class .children
   }
 })
```

```css
.list-group > a {
  color: Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a>Biologie</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a>Chimie</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a>Non classé</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a>Physique</a>
      <ul class='children'>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a>Physique quantique</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT . don't know why you would want this. IF you want this so you can just style those li's you could easily use CSS for that, using `:not(.class) > li`

Comment: Hi, I understood many things, thanks a lot for your time ! Have a good day !

Comment: @ThomasHabets glad i could help.

Comment: `parentClass != ("children")` and if there is more than one class this fails.... Why are you not just doing hasClass?

Comment: @epascarello because .. tired :) sorry . thanks for pointing that out. edited . i tend to over complicate things after a a day's work